# groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize how to add xsi:nil="true"

Tags: groovy

Is it possible for the groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize method to add the `xsi:nil="true"` namespace to null nodes? I have an application where I use the XmlUtil.serialize utility to write an xml to file, but it doesn't automatically place the `xsi:nil="true"` namespace for null nodes.

```
The XmlUtil.serialize method condenses nodes by taking null nodes like 
<n:test></n:test> and converting it to <n:test/> but I need it to insert
the null namespace like this <n:test xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Is this possible w/ the groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize method or maybe there's another way to do. I need to do this after xml payload has been constructed since it uses StringBuilder to build the xml data.

Is there a way in Java/Groovy to run an xml string through a pre-processor similar to Microsoft's XSL pre-processor and use the following xml template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>            
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(text())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: do it before XmlUtil.serialize(), it's quite simple algorithm to check if value is empty/null then add the `nil` attribute.

Comment: The xml payload is created using StringBuilder and would require a ton conditional checks to do it programmatically since the xml data is huge.  I was hoping the XmlUtil.serialize() method was smart enough to add it since it's checking for blank nodes and condensing it already, but I guess not.